# Flutter - what causes XMLHttpRequest error

Tags: flutter, dart, xmlhttprequest

I would like to know if the 'XMLHttpRequest Error' thrown by http package is always due to missing CORS policy header?

The expection thrown in this instance is of Type ClientException - the only things that I can read is the message (XMLHttpRequest Error) and uri. So how would I know it is because of the above.

I get intermittent(and infrequent) errors in the logs, and the CORS policy header is correctly set on the server.

I want to rule out any other causes of XMLHttpRequest Error. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the full error log being thrown?